# Customizable images for an iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, sdk, static-libraries

We are building an iphone SDK. It contains the usual suspects:

- include directory with the header files
- lib directory with the static library
- Resources directory with a .bundle file containing strings & images

Everything is working fine so far. Now we have several projects which
are based on the SDK and we want to give our customers the opportunity
to customize the appearance.

For example:

- Customer A wants to replace the background image with his creation.
- Customer B wants only to replace the default logo with his creation.
- Customer C wants both.

etc. etc.

If the customer does not provide a specific image, the default image in
the .bundle file will be used.

Question: What is the best solution to allow customizable images which also
seamlessly integrates into the development process ?

- Non-developers can edit and replace the given images.
- We can always ship a customized version to the customers or build it.
- There is no collision between the default and the customized images.

The current favored solution is to add a Runscript phase in all dependent
projects which is overwriting all image files with images in a specified project
directory.

Is there an even better solution ?

Comment: _We are building an iphone SDK._ - Devs from Apple askes questions on SO? o_O

Comment: SDK is simply an abbreviation for a framework or toolkit. The ZBarSDK e.g. is not from Apple and still calls itself SDK. And no, I am not working for Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have similar requirements and we came up with the same solution (a pre-compile time script overwrites the default images / other resources in the application build folder). Furthermore we made it configurable from the project settings the source folder of the customized images with User-Defined variables in Build Settings (called BRAND_NAME). So the following Run script was added as the first Build Phase:

```
rsync -r --exclude=.svn Resources/brands/${BRAND_NAME}/images Resources
```

This has an additional advantage that you can change the BRAND_NAME variable per compile target so you can build different versions of the product right from XCode without any manual configuration.